# I'm trying to use group policy in .NET

Tags: c#

I'm using .NET Framework 4.0 and trying to update group policy.

I have this working C++ code:

```
auto hres = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

if (hres == S_OK || hres == S_FALSE || hres == RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE)
{
    CComPtr<IGroupPolicyObject> lgp;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_GroupPolicyObject, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGroupPolicyObject, (LPVOID*)&lgp);
}
```

And I try to reproduce it in C#

```
Guid ext = new Guid(0x35378EAC, 0x683F, 0x11D2, 0xA8, 0x9A, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x4F, 0xBB, 0xCF, 0xA2);
Guid CLSID_GroupPolicyObject = new Guid("EA502722-A23D-11D1-A7D3-0000F87571E3");
Guid IID_IGroupPolicyObject = new Guid("EA502723-A23D-11D1-A7D3-0000F87571E3");

int hres = Ole32.CoInitializeEx(IntPtr.Zero, Ole32.COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

if (hres == 0 || hres == 1 || hres == -2147417850)
{
    IntPtr lgpPtr;
    int hr = Ole32.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_GroupPolicyObject, IntPtr.Zero, 1, IID_IGroupPolicyObject, out lgpPtr);
}
```

but `hr` is `E_NOINTERFACE` when in C++ it's OK:

```
static class Ole32
{
    public const int COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED = 0x2;

    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    public static extern int CoInitializeEx(IntPtr pvReserved, int dwCoInit);

    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    public static extern void CoUninitialize();

    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    public static extern int CoCreateInstance(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid rclsid,
        IntPtr pUnkOuter,
        uint dwClsContext,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid,
        out IntPtr ppv);
}
```

Comment: This would be better with a Powershell script.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/get-gpo?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: For one thing `CoInitializeEx` is already called by most frameworks already. And you should be using .Net's built-in COM interop functionality, by creating the `interface`s themselves and assigning them the correct `Guid` attributes.

Comment: This is completely the wrong way to do this in .NET. You need to import the correct TLB library, which will automatically create interfaces with the right GUIDs, you probablly want gpedit.tlb if you can find it somewhere, maybe the WINAPI SDK and you need this class from it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gpedit/nn-gpedit-igrouppolicyobject You don't call `CoCreateInstance`, you just `Activator.CreateInstance`. And any case you should instead just use `Powershell.Create` and run one of the PS scripts that does all this for you.